# Searching an array for sum of values

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have a system that generates values in a text file which contains values as below

> Line 1 : Total value possible
>
> Line 2 : No of elements in the array
>
> Line 3(extra lines if required) : The numbers themselves

I am now thinking of an approach where I can subtract the total value from the first integer in the array and then searching the array for the remainder and then doing the same until the pair is found.

The other approach is to add the two integers in the array on a permutation and combination basis and finding the pair.

As per my analysis the first solution is better since it cuts down on the number of iterations.Is my analysis correct here and is there any other better approach?

Edit :
I'll give a sample here to make it more clear
Line 1 : 200
Line 2=10
Line 3 : 10 20 80 78 19 25 198 120 12 65

Now the valid pair here is 80,120 since it sums up to 200 (represented in line one as Total Value possible in the input file) and their positions in the array would be 3,8.So find to this pair I listed out my approach where I take the first element and I subtract it with the Total value possible and searching the other element through basic search algorithms.

Using the example here I first take 10 and subtract it with 200 which gives 190,then I search for 190,if it is found then the pair is found otherwise continue the same process.

Comment: I am not following. Are you looking for a subset of the array with the given sum? Or a pair with the given sum? If the first - you have yourself an NP-Hard problem which is known as the subset-sum problem.

Comment: Maybe you could give an example of an input with the solution? This would probably clarify things.

Comment: what does your "doing the same until the pair is found "mean???

Comment: Sorry for the late response.I have edited my question.Sorry if I have mislead anyone.

Comment: Is each sum required to have only two members? For example, is 10, 20, 80, 78, 12 a valid solution to the example problem?

Comment: Yes,I am looking for a pair only and not a subset.So combinations greater than two will not be my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to find a pair (2) numbers which sum to a third number, in general you'll have something like:

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
   for(j=i+1;j<N;j++)
      if(numbers[i]+numbers[j]==result)
         The answer is <i,j>
         end
```

which is O(n^2). However, it is possible to do better.

If the list of numbers is sorted (which takes O(n log n) time) then you can try:

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
   binary_search 'numbers[i+1:N]' for result-numbers[i]
   if search succeeds:
      The answer is <i, search_result_index>
      end
```

That is you can step through each number and then do a binary search on the remaining list for its companion number. This takes O(n log n) time. You may need to implement the `search` function above yourself as built-in functions may just walk down the list in O(n) time leading to an O(n^2) result.

For both methods, you'll want to check to for the special case that the current number is equal to your result.

Both algorithms use no more space than is taken by the array itself.

Apologies for the coding style, I'm not terribly familiar with Java and it's the ideas here which are important.

Comment: Ok,thats good,but let us now add the complexity/runtime of the sorting algorithm combined with the algorithm that I have posted here.So now there are two things to be done,one is the sorting part next is the searching part.So both complexities combined,does it perform well.

Comment: @Madusudanan, your algorithm runs in O(n^2) time and thus is to be avoided. The sorting algorithm runs in O(n log n) time, as does the subsequent search. Combined, they should still out-perform your algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is vague, but if you are looking for a pair in the array that is summed to a certain number, it can be done in `O(n)` on average using hash tables.

Iterate the array, and for each element:

(1) Check if it is in the table. If it is - stop and return there is such a pair.

(2) Else: insert `num-element` to the hash table.

If your iteration terminated without finding a match - there is no such pair.

**pseudo code:**

```
checkIfPairExists(arr,num):
   set <- new empty hash set
   for each element in arr:
        if set.contains(element):
            return true
         else:
            set.add(num-element)
    return false
```

The general problem of "is there a subset that sums to a certain number" is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard), and is known as the [**subset-sum problem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), so there is no known polynomial solution to it.

Comment: This is very nice, amit! Together we have covered a whole range of time complexities :-)

Comment: Hi amit.I did not quite understand your pseudo code.Are you saying that my question is here is non-deterministic.Is my solution correct here?

Comment: @Madusudanan: Your first solution is not efficient, it runs in `O(n^2)` while it can be done much faster - `O(n)` as the solution I suggested shows. Note that my solution is assuming you are looking for a PAIR that sums to a number. If you are looking for any subset (and not only a pair) - the problem is NP-Complete - which means it cannot be solved polynomially! (or it least we believe it cannot). If you are indeed looking for a pair - you can ignore this comment regarding NP-Completeness.

Comment: @Madusudanan: Also: What part of the pseudo code didn't you understand? Are you familiar with java's [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

Comment: I am afraid I am new to hashset.Anyways give me some time.I'll try to implement your pseudo code.Thanks for the your input here.

Comment: @amit Hash sets don't help when you are looking for worst case complexity. The elements can just happen to be in the same bucket.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: True, but the odds for that to happen are slim. You can obviously use a `TreeSet` or sorting based solution if you cannot afford this chance. Note that I explicitly indicated that the complexity is O(n) on **average**.

Comment: I am looking for a pair here and not more than that.I need to find two unknowns in the array.Is my problem NP complete here?

Comment: @Madusudanan In this case the problem is NOT NP Complete and is solveable in linear time with the algorithm I suggested.